# How can I make it so players can't destroy farmland by jumping on it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I make it so players can't destroy farmland by jumping on it?

I am using java edition 1.16. I need this for my Minecraft map where I don't want players to be able to destroy farmland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using a server, the WorldGuard plugin can be used.
To create a server with plugin support, this is a good tutorial:

Stop the server and delete "world", "world_nether" and "world_the_end". Copy the world to "world".

Download [WorldGuard](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/bukkit-plugins/worldguard) and add it into the server's "plugins" folder.

Start the server back up.

Set `gamemode` to `adventure`.

Give yourself cheats (`/op <player>`).

For a guide on how to use WorldGuard here's another tutorial (I just can't be bothered to write the whole thing):

.

The flag used to prevent block-trampling is "block-trampling" (not too surprisingly). It does not affect operators.

Unfortunately, to distribute the map you need to distribute the whole server folder (excluding "cache", for copyright reasons).

Sorry if this wasn't the most ideal solution.

Comment: I need it without plugin, just with commands in minecraft or functions of minecraft, i can use datapack